# Listen for Beacon Frames on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, network-programming

First of all: This thread is no duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381193/how-to-capture-a-beacon-frame-from-wlan-in-windows).
Now my question. I am searching for some kind of winapi that provides low level access to frames on the networkcard(OSI-Layer 2). I would need to get the raw data of Beacon-Frames, my networkcard captures. 
And the next step would be that I should be able to send a raw frame. But I actually could not find anything. Do you know something that provides access to the raw beacon frames?

Comment: How is it not a duplicate? It looks pretty similar to me. "I want to access certain fields of the beacon frame" vs "I want to get the raw data of the beacon frame"

Comment: I also want to send a raw frame.